# Joomla 3.4 Bootstrap.css not loading on every page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I was wondering if there was a way to force load the bootstrap.css or identify why it isn't loading on certain pages. the Bootstrap JS file is loading without a problem on all pages. Specifically, the CSS file doesnt seem to load with the ACYMailing Frontend module or Chronoforms. Could this be some sort of conflict? Any suggestion on how this can be rectified would be most appreciated.
Regards
Donna

Comment: Maybe these extensions remove Bootstrap from the `<head>`. I'd suggest contacting the developers of both extensions just to double check

Answer (score 0):

You can load in the template, bootstrap version you want to use.

Create a directory called "js" in the template and lther for the "css"

Then add this in the template, after placing files.

```
$doc->addScript($tpath.'/js/bootstrap.min.js');
$doc->addStyleSheet($tpath.'/css/bootstrap_3.css');
```

To avoid conflicts, how not to load js files it is as follows:

```
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js']);
```

In this case, we remove the bootstrap.min.js joomla file loaded by default.